# The role of compactness in measure theory

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $E \subset \mathbb{R}^{d}$ and $\mathcal{O}_{n}$ is the open set
\begin{align*}
  \mathcal{O}_{n}=\left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^{d}: d(x, E)<\frac{1}{n}\right\}
 \end{align*}
If $E$ is compact, then $m(E)=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} m\left(\mathcal{O}_{n}\right)$. I wonder what are some examples that this equality does not hold when $E$ is closed and unbounded, or $E$ is open and bounded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the case of open and bounded $E$ take $E=[0,1]\setminus C$ where $C$ is a fat Cantor set with $0 <m(C) <1$. Then $m(O_n) \to m(\overline E)=1$ whereas  $m(E)<1$.

Answer (score 2):

For closed and unbounded case:

Take $d=1$ $E=\Bbb N$. Then $O_n=\bigcup_{k\in\Bbb N}(k-1/n,k+1/n)$, where the sets are pairwise disjoint for $n\ge2$, for example.

For any fixed $n\ge2$, $m(O_n)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2}
{n}=\frac{2}{n}\sum_{k=1}^\infty 1=+\infty$. But $m(\Bbb N)=0$.

PS: In the general case, take $E$ to be any sequence of different points in $\Bbb R^d$ going to infinity.